# How to invoke a method again and again until it returns a `Future` value containing `None`

Tags: scala, future

Given a method that returns a `Future` like this...

```
def remove(id: String): Future[Option[User]] = Future {
  // removes and returns the user identified by `id`
}
```

... how do I invoke it again and again until it returns a `Future` value containing `None`?

**EDIT**

Perhaps it is worth to mention that I don't need to collect the results. I just need to invoke the method as long as it finds an user to remove. The idea would be to have a `loop` that stops when `remove` returns `Future[None]`.

Comment: Do you want to collect the results or...

Comment: No, I don't need to collect the results - see my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone commented earlier that there's no point.

The surprise for me was that there's no quickie for lazily consuming the futures.  `Future.find` is like `firstCompletedOf`, and doesn't mean `find first in traversable order`.

```
scala> import concurrent._, ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits._

scala> import java.util.concurrent.atomic._
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._

scala> val count = new AtomicInteger(10)
count: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger = 10

scala> def f(s: String) = Future { if (count.decrementAndGet <= 0) None else Some(s) }
f: (s: String)scala.concurrent.Future[Option[String]]

scala> def g(ss: List[String]): Future[List[String]] = f("hello") flatMap { case None => Future.successful(ss) case Some(s) => g(s :: ss) }
g: (ss: List[String])scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]

scala> g(Nil)
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@65a15628

scala> .value
res1: Option[scala.util.Try[List[String]]] = Some(Success(List(hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello)))
```

Illustrating the utility of not blocking:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.util._
import concurrent._, ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._

class Work {
  val count = new AtomicInteger(10)
  def f(s: String) = Future {
    if (count.decrementAndGet <= 0) None else Some(s)
  } andThen {
    case Success(Some(x)) => Console println s"Calculated $x"
    case Success(None)    => Console println "Done."
    case _                => Console println "Failed."
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.util._
import concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._
defined class Work
```

Showing the `Stream` version, which won't calculate the prefix until the consuming thread steps through the blocking Awaits:

```
scala> val work = new Work
work: Work = Work@1b45c0e

scala> Stream continually work.f("hello") takeWhile { x => Await.result(x, duration.Duration.Inf).nonEmpty }
Calculated hello
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[String]]] = Stream(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@66629f63, ?)

scala> .toList
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Done.
res1: List[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[String]]] = List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@66629f63, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@610db97e, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6f0628de, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3fabf088, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1e392345, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@12f3afb5, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4ced35ed, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2c22a348, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7bd69e82)

scala> .foreach (Console println _.value.get)
Success(Some(hello))
Success(Some(hello))
[snip]
```

The other behavior, probably more desirable, where you get a Future that holds the result of calculating the prefix:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  val work = new Work
  def g(ss: List[String]): Future[List[String]] = work.f("hello") flatMap {
    case None => Future.successful(ss)
    case Some(s) => g(s :: ss)
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

work: Work = Work@796d3c9f
g: (ss: List[String])scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]

scala> g(Nil)
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@99a78d7
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello

scala> Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Calculated hello
Done.
```

Use the future:

```
scala> .value
res5: Option[scala.util.Try[List[String]]] = Some(Success(List(hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello)))
```

Comment: With Scalaz you could do something like `StreamT.unfoldM(())(_ => f("hello").map(_.map(_ -> ()))).toStream`, but right, I don't think the standard library provides any shortcuts here.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream#continually` to do the same thing endlessly, and `Stream#takeWhile` to halt it at a certain point.
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

```
Stream.continually(/*remove*/).takeWhile(/*not Future[None]*/)
```

Comment: As usual, the downvoter failed to comment. You must block to eval. `Stream continually f("hello") takeWhile { x => Await.result(x, duration.Duration.Inf).nonEmpty }`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import concurrent._, ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._

val count = new AtomicInteger(10)

def f(s: String) = Future {
  if (count.decrementAndGet <= 0) None else Some(s)
}

Iterator continually {
  f("hello")
} takeWhile {
  Await.result(_, duration.Duration.Inf).nonEmpty
} foreach { _.map { _.map {
  println
}}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: That's the same as the Stream answer. I updated to show it blocking and the other not blocking. Now to look at scalaz as evangelized by Mr Brown.

Comment: BTW, if you want to block, you might as well just sit in a while loop.