# Is there sequential Future.find?

Tags: scala, stream, functional-programming, future, sequential

I have some side-effectful function,

```
def f(): Future[Int] = {
  val n = Random.nextInt()
  println(s"Generated $n")
  Future(n)
}
```

and I want to execute it repeatedly until predicate returns true.

```
def success(n: Int): Boolean = n % 2 == 0
```

My plan is to build `Stream` of results

```
val s = Stream.fill(10)(f)
```

and then use `Future.find` to get the first result that satisfies predicate.

```
Future.find(s)(success) map println
```

The problem is that `Future.find` runs all the futures in parallel and I want it to execute futures sequentially one after the other until predicate returns true.

```
scala> Future.find(s)(success) map println
Generated -237492703
Generated -935476293
Generated -1155819556
Generated -375506595
Generated -912504491
Generated -1307379057
Generated -1522265611
Generated 1163971151
Generated -516152076
res8: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@37d28f02
Some(-1155819556)
```

The question is how to execute stream of futures sequentially until predicate returns true? Are there any suitable functions in standard or third-party library?

Comment: You may have a look at `scalaz-stream` or `iteratee`

Comment: Duplicate for the std lib case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349318/how-to-invoke-a-method-again-and-again-until-it-returns-a-future-value-contain

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Stream I suggest using another approach. Using The Future's filter and recoverWith  recursively:

```
def findFirst[A](futureGen: => Future[A], predicate: A => Boolean): Future[A] = {
  futureGen.filter(predicate).recoverWith { case _ => findFirst(futureGen, predicate) }
}

findFirst(f, success)
```

This will call the Futures one after the other until 'success' will return true.

Comment: Looks like hand-crafted recursion I'm currently using, except for `filter` and `recoverWith` :)

Comment: Well...  Sometimes you should stick to the simple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make the futures we aren't interested in fail:

```
val s1 = s.map(_.filter(success))
```

Now you can combine two such futures and get the first successful value using `fallbackTo`. And just fold the stream, starting with a known-bad future:

```
def firstSuccess[T](stream: Stream[Future[T]]): Future[T] = 
  if (stream.isEmpty)
    Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)
  else
    stream.head.fallbackTo(firstSuccess(stream.tail))
```

Comment: `foldLeft` executes all futures, but I want execute just enough futures to satisfy the predicate.

Comment: @lambdas Oops. Of course you are right, you need a lazy right fold instead. Edited.

Comment: And edited again, since pattern matching the stream isn't lazy enough.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts! I still think there is an easier way to solve it using standard library, scalaz, twitter futures or something else I'm not aware of..

Comment: Oh, scalaz does include lazy right fold, called `foldr`. I think replacing `foldLeft` with `foldr` in my original solution should work, modulo argument order. See also answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892701/abort-early-in-a-fold

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, then you will have to block the thread to proceed sequentially. You can use Await to accomplish that.

```
scala> def f(): Future[Int] = {
 |   val n = Random.nextInt()
 |   println(s"Generated $n")
 |   Future(n)
 | }
f: ()scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> def success(n: Int): Boolean = n % 2 == 0
success: (n: Int)Boolean

scala> val s = Stream.fill(10)(f)
```

Using your way, I get

```
scala> Future.find(s)(success) map println
Generated 551866055
Generated -561348666
Generated -1103407834
Generated -812310371
Generated -1544170923
Generated 2131361419
Generated -236722325
Generated -1473890302
Generated -82395856
Some(-561348666)
res16: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@15a2d71
```

I should get answer as Some(-561348666), which you can get as

```
scala> s.find(x => success(Await.result(x,1 seconds))).get onSuccess {case p=> println(p)}
-561348666
```

Comment: I would like to get Future[Option[Int]], is it ok to just wrap your last expression in `Future {...}`? `Future` with `Await` inside, looks strange;)

Comment: I dont know the way you are going to use it. You can wrap the expression but it may or may not be correct depending on your use case. s.find(x => success(Await.result(x,1 seconds))).get returns Future[Int]